# Why is my form not cleared?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have made two controllers. One for adding data in the database via an API call, and a second one for sending an email. Weirdly (for now because I don't understand why) the adding functionality works fine and clears the form after the action, the second controller for sending the email doesn't clear the form and also doesn't do the console.log, it does however sends the email perfectly.

If i remove the + 'sendmail' from the emailController the form is cleared and console.log works fine also. but ofcourse the email is not send then.

I will place the pieces of codes of both controllers here. Hoping someone can help me finding out why the controller for sending the email doesnt act the way i want (and expected to).

thanks for any help.

The add review functionality

```
.controller('ReviewController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.addReview = function () {
    $http.post(API, $scope.review)
      .success(function () {
        $scope.reviews.push($scope.review);
        $scope.review = {};
      })
      .error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = 'Posting review not successful';
        console.log(data);
      });
  };
})
```

the sendEmail controller

```
.controller('emailController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.sendMail = function () {
    $http.post(API + 'sendmail', $scope.email)
      .success(function () {
        console.log('Mail send');
        $scope.email = {};
      })
      .error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = 'Posting review not successful';
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Mail not send');
      });
  };
});
```

Comment: if "console.log" does not work, then there is no response, the error at the query level, is not it?

Comment: Sounds logical. But like i said, when i remove the + 'sendmail', it works, the console.log and clearing the form. Also the addReview functionality works perfectly, and i seem to do exactly the same thing there.

Comment: go to network tab of your browser's dev tool and check whether URL has   200 as response code or not? Tell me whats the response code.

Comment: `$http.post(API + '/sendmail', $scope.email)`

Comment: Hi Kalhano, the extra slash you added is not needed. var API contains a slash already 'http://ip/'. if i add another slash as you proposed, the email isn't send anymore.

Comment: @rishi, the result is positive, i get a 200 error code. but the line directly under it is: POST, status: pending. It seems to wait for a response before the next lines of codes are executed. So the console.log and clearing the form. Now i only need to figure out why ;)